# which fields bank validates compulsory while processing credit card?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card, banking

I have worked with some of the payment gateways like PayHub, Braintree, Balanced. at the time of processing credit cards; I submitted a bunch of `credit card` and its details as `CVV, expiry date, Name of card holder, address`.

I come across that, through the same gateway, some times the details are being checked but some times not at all. After contacting to support team of gateway, they told me that, the details are checked by banks and varies by each bank.

Can anybody tell, which are the fields that bank compulsory validates?

Comment: Card number and Expiry are typically the bare minimum, CVV, address/post/zip code are optional and the need for their submission is dependent upon the clearing bank/card scheme

Comment: What Alex said, only adding that issue number (where present on card) is always required.

Comment: @PaulG did'nt get what is the issue number exactly.

Comment: It's a number embossed onto the front of the card that shows how many times the card has been issued/re-issued. Not present on all card schemes, but where it is present it is required.

Answer (score 1):

Card number and expiry date are always required. Worth noting that it should be valid to submit 'expired' cards to the payment processor, who in certain circumstances may accept expired cards (particularly for refund processing).

Issue number may be embossed onto the front of the card for certain card schemes. Where present it is required.

Where card details have been captured by magnetic stripe, then submission of the full track 2 details are required.

All other card related fields (name, start date, cvv) are optional. Start date is not used during processing at all, and name is only used in rare circumstances. CVV combined with address details may be used to perform CV2/AVS check to validate the cardholder. In many cases passing CV2/AVS data will reduce the gateway processing fees.